# Why can Pygame questions be considered Stack Overflow questions?

Tags: discussion, questions, scope

If anything, wouldn't Pygame questions be better placed under the Game Development site? Just wondering why they are accepted.

Comment: Sometimes a question simply fits more than one site. In which case the asker should make a decision, because cross-posting is frowned upon.

Comment: That makes sense, I thought that Pygame could only be considered a game development type question, but I assume the question, since it involves code can fit other sites. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If it's code, it's okay on Stack Overflow.  If it's a general code question, it's [explicitly forbidden](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) on GameDev.SE.

Most of the Pygame questions that I've seen fall under the "general code" category, and fall significantly far away from the explicitly on-topic points of discussion there, like level design.

It *may* be the case that a question asked here would fit over there, but before a blanket statement like that could be made, you have to be certain that it would be accepted over there.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! Just making sure, I've seen questions about Pygame on both sites.

Comment: I noticed a few while I was glancing over there as well, but those were the ones that did fall in the scope of what was accepted.  If it's a straight-up code question, it's got a (better) chance here than it does over there, though.

Answer (score 3):

Because questions about code are on-topic.

I don't know what Pygame is, but if one using it has a question about code, it is welcome on SO.

That is, of course, when the question adheres to [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).